# Adding a delay to a hover function

Tags: jquery

I have this code which triggers a mega menu.

```
    $('li#locations a').hover(function(){
$('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown();
}); 

$('#locationsSuperNav').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).slideUp();
});
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="nav_509815">
<li><a href="/Culture/cultureHome">Culture</a></li>
<li><a href="/Advantage/advantageHome">Advantage</a></li>
<li><a href="/Testimonials/parentstories">Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="/Programs/programs">Programs</a></li>
<li class="locations" id="locations"><a href="/Locations/locationsHome">Locations</a></li>
<li><a href="/Careers/careers">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="locationsSuperNav" class="" style="display: none;">All the content goes here</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is add a simple timer to the original hover event. That way, if a user accidentally touches the a tag, it won't fire unless they sit there for half a second or so. Any suggestions??

Comment: go for hoverintent plugin its very nice todo these type of stuff

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should look at using jQuery's [delay() function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).</strike>

**Update (see edits for history)**

Alright. Now I much better understand your problem. Thank you for the clarification. I think this code does what you want it to do. You can play with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/57eGD/

```
$('li#locations a').mouseenter(function() {
    var curElement = this;
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
       $('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown();
    }, 650);

    // Use data so trigger can be cleared.
    $(curElement).data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
});

$('#locationsSuperNav').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Basically, delay() wouldn't work for you as that only delays the event, but it does not allow an event to be canceled. As a result, it won't work for you because, even if you delay the slideDown() event, it will still happen if the user mouses over. Because of this, you have to use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) which does allow for a cancellation. However, the (sort of) tricky part is that you have to be able to tell the timeout to cancel. This is where jQuery's [data function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) comes into play. This function allows you to attach data of any type to DOM elements. So, in your case, you should attach it to the element you care about triggering the event (in this case, `$('li#locations a')`) which will allow you to cancel if you leave the element before the event triggers. You can adjust the 650 for a longer or shorter delay.

The other thing to note is that hover() should work here instead of mouseenter and mouseleave. It should be something like this:

```
$('li#locations a').hover(function() {
    var curElement = this;
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
       $('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown();
    }, 650);

    // Use data so trigger can be cleared.
    $(curElement).data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
});
```

I hope this helps you! Good learning experience for me as well.

Comment: For some reason the delay function is not working for the hover event and the hover intent plugin looks like it won't work either. I need to delay the initial hover, not the mouseout. The other issue I have is the hover function is showing a separate div. Hover Intent is fixed on the parent element if I read properly. I need to have the #locationsSuperNav stay open when the user leaves the li. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @mmsa - Updated the answer. Does this help at all? If not, I will try for round three. :-p

Comment: Make sure you have the latest jQuery.  .delay is 1.4+

Comment: @JasCav, thanks for the update. Sorry for the confusion. Here's what is happening. I have a standard nav ul on a site. When the user hovers over li#locations a, I need to have a div which is hidden on the page show up. Basically creating a mega-menu. The mouseleave event hides the megamenu when the user's mouse leaves that div. The div extends the full width of the screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: @mmsa - Can you add some of your HTML to your post?

Comment: @mmsa - Okay. I think the answer is what you are looking for now. If it's not, please let me know, but I think this is it. Please don't forget to accept if this answers your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`jquery.hoverIntent.js` is exactly what you are looking for.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent

Comment: yeah hover is apt for these type of things

Comment: From what I can read, the delay happens on the mouseout event. What I need to delay is the hover event. Any other suggestions?